# splitting/merging matrices in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am trying to split a Matrix into segments, perform some manipulation of the segments and then merge the segments into a complete matrix again.

To split, I'm doing:

```
for(int j = 0; j < segments; ++j)
        {
            Rect r;
            if(j == lastSegment)
            {
                r = Rect(j * segmentWidth, 0, lastWidth, origHei);
            }
            else
            {
                r = Rect(j * segmentWidth, 0, segmentWidth - 1, origHei);
            }

            tmpFrame(r).copyTo(segmentMats[j]);
}
```

Then to merge them I try:

```
Mat fullFrame;
for(int i = 0; i < maxSegments; ++i)
{
    int segNum = i % segments;
    Rect r;

    if( segNum == 0)  // 1st segment of frame
    {
        fullFrame.create(origWid, origHei, segmentMats[i].type());
        r = Rect(0, 0, segmentWidth - 1, origHei); 
    }
    else if (segNum == lastSegment)
    {
        r = Rect((i * segmentWidth), 0, lastWidth, origHei);
    }
    else
    {
        r = Rect((i * segmentWidth), 0, segmentWidth - 1, origHei); 
    }

    segmentMats[i].copyTo(fullFrame(r));
}
```

But I keep getting a failed assertion,

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x
>   + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat

I don't see how this code could set borders outside the assertion values. Can someone see my error?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the replies. To clarify my variables, I've listed how they are computed below.

origWid and origHei are the height and width of the entire frame

segments = the number of vertical segments a frame is divided into. So segments = 2 means the frame is divided in half vertically.

lastSegment = segments - 1; since they are 0-inclusive indexed, that last segment has this index

segmentWidth = origWid / segments; this floors in case origWid is not evenly divisible  by segments

lastWidth = origWid - (lastSegment * segmentWidth); this takes care of the case that origWid is not evenly divisible by segments and captures the number of columns left over in the last segment

segmentMats is an array of *segments* Mats

segNum = the order of the segment. So if segments == 2, segNum == 0 is the left half of the frame and segNum == 1 is the right half of the frame

Comment: How much are `segments`, `segmentWidth`, `lastWidth`, `origHei` and `origWid`?

Comment: my tip would be to check whether `lastWidth` is correct and whether `-1` is correct. Although I don't understand the meaning of `segNum` and `segments`. Maybe it would be nice if you can explain how you want to split with a drawing. And variable values would be helpful as AldurDisciple mentioned.